# Obj-C OS X Delete application from /Applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am writing an application to remove a piece of software and its files from OS X. I can delete everything else except the .app and a folder in /Applications. I am using `AuthetificationExecuteWithPriviledges`, I know that it is deprecated, so could that be giving me admin issues when attempting to move the .app to the trash bin? When I step through the process I see an `NSCocoaErrorDomain`, with code `513`. I did a quick search for it, and saw it is related to a permissions error. My other theory is that my path to the application is incorrect. I am using:
`NSString *ibmNotesApplication = @"/Applications/IBM Notes.app";`

If you are wondering why I am trying to delete Lotus Notes, it is because the Notes uninstaller provided by IBM doesn't have all of the functionality I would like. So, I am writing one that removes notes and all files related to it so we can have a fresh install.

Here is a snippet of code where I move an item in the array to the trash bin.

```
 if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:object])
        {
            NSURL *objectURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:object];
            NSURL *trashedObject;
            NSError *error;

            //Moves item to trash bin and update log
            if([filemanager trashItemAtURL:objectURL resultingItemURL:&trashedObject error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Trashed %@ to %@",objectURL, trashedObject);
                self.textfield.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@", self.textfield.stringValue, @"Trashed ", objectURL, @" to ", trashedObject, @"\n"];
            }
```

Comment: AppCleaner works for me: http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help mattt, I wrote my question hastily. @trojanfoe, I would really like to write my own utility rather than relying on another tool to hopefully remove Notes, along with some Eclipse plist files.

Comment: not 100% sure what `Authetification` is... but googling leads me back here..

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question, the function AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is a deprecated function and has been for quite a while now. I suggest you start by following Apple's advice of factoring out the privileged process into a separate privileged helper tool, which is launched with the help of launchd.

You can follow the example code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html).

If the permission problem still exists, then at least you've gone about refactoring your code to the right way of doing things, knowing that it will be supported for future versions of the OS.